# Consulta con react a firebase revienta el servicio, ¿ En donde estoy fallando?

Tags: javascript, sql, reactjs, firebase, web

estoy aprendiendo React y aun tengo algo verde el tema de las consultas con firebase y tengo algunas dudas relacionadas con esto.

Tengo el siguiente codigo actualmente :

```
const Tactive = () => {
var keys = [];
var childData = [];
const[data2,setData2] = useState([]);
const[data3,setData3] = useState([]);
var query = fire.database().ref('Torneos').orderByKey();
query.once("value")
    .then((snapshot) => {
        if(snapshot.exists()){
        snapshot.forEach( childSnapshot => {
             keys.push(childSnapshot.key);
             childData.push(childSnapshot.val());

        });
        setData2([...childData]);
        setData3([...keys])
    } else {
    console.log("No data available");
}
}).catch((error) => {
console.error(error);
});
```

Esto me devuelve los distintos campos de cada objeto de la tabla "Torneos" , por ejemplo el nombre del torneo, su descripción, etc..

Y en esta tabla lo muestro todo :

```
     return (
    <div>
        <h1>Torneos activos</h1>

        <div className="App">
            <Table striped bordered hover variant="dark">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>IdTorneo</th>
                    <th>Banner</th>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Fecha</th>
                    <th>Descripción</th>
                    <th>Ganador</th>
                    <th>Juego</th>
                    <th>Nº Maximo de equipos</th>
                    <th>Jugadores por equipo</th>
                    <th>Plataforma</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {data2.map((childData) => {
                            return (
                                <tr key={childData.date}>
                                    <td>{childData.id}</td>
                                    <td>{childData.banner}</td>
                                    <td>{childData.nombre}</td>
                                    <td>{childData.fecha}</td>
                                    <td>{childData.descripcion}</td>
                                    <td>{childData.idWinner}</td>
                                    <td>{childData.juego}</td>
                                    <td>{childData.nequipos}</td>
                                    <td>{childData.playersEquipo}</td>
                                    <td>{childData.plataforma}</td>
                                    <Button variant="info">Modificar</Button>
                                    <Button variant="warning">Eliminar</Button>
                                </tr>
                            );
                })}
                </tbody>
            </Table>
        </div>
    </div>

);
```

El problema es , que esto me muestra correctamente todo, pero pasados unos segundos la página se bloquea y se cierra. He descubierto metiendo `console.log()` dentro del foreach y de la consulta , que nunca deja de acumular registros en consola de llamada a console.log y creo que puede ser por esto

Muchas gracias !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> He descubierto metiendo console.log() dentro del foreach y de la consulta , que nunca deja de acumular registros en consola de llamada a console.log y creo que puede ser por esto

Parece ser, que no se esta controlando el número de devoluciones (re-renders) para la secuencia asincrónica `firebase-ReactJS` involucrada.

Se puede intentar lo siguiente:

```
    const Tactive = () => {
    
        const[data2,setData2] = useState([]);
        const[data3,setData3] = useState([]);
        useEffect(()=>{
            var keys = [];
            var childData = [];
            var query = fire.database().ref('Torneos').orderByKey();
            //Inicio de la secuencia async firebase
            query.once("value")
            .then((snapshot) => {
                if(snapshot.exists()){
                    snapshot.forEach( childSnapshot => {
                        keys.push(childSnapshot.key);
                        childData.push(childSnapshot.val());
                    });
                    //secuencia async ReactJS
                    setData2([...childData]);
                    setData3([...keys])
                } else {
                    console.log("No data available");
                }
           }).catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
           });
        }, []);

    //demas código
    //return ...
    }
```

Toda la operacion asincrónica `firebase` se envuelve en un hook `useEffect`, se controla el número de devoluciones del componente para cada llamada a los setters (`setData2`, `setData3`) de `useState`.

Esa pieza de código no parece necesitar dependencias, así que se pasa un `array` vacío como segundo argumento para `useEffect`. Con esta configuración, la pieza de código dentro de `useEffect` solo se ejecutará una vez que este montado el componente `Tactive`.